# Facebook image as Large Icon Notification appears as white on different phones?

Tags: android, bitmap, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop, notification-icons

I am having this problem with creating and sending notifications correctly. I read the new `Lollipop 5.0 update` notification design specification here: https://material.google.com/style/icons.html and https://material.google.com/patterns/notifications.html and I realize that Icons need to be `white` in order to display correctly. That is fine and I totally understand that, but I want my notification to show a picture, which obviously cannot be white. However, what is really confusing me is the fact that when I try to render the notification on my phone, everything works fine. It looks something like this:

[image]

However, on my friend's phone, it looks like a white square, something like this:

[image]

It's odd because we both have the same version of Android, version 6.0.1. Here is the code I used to send the notification:

```
private class NotificationPicture extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        Context context;
        String userId;
        String postId;
        String name;
        String notificationBody;
        String from;

        public NotificationPicture(Context context) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            userId = params[0];
            postId = params[1];
            name = params[2];
            notificationBody = params[3];
            from = params[4];
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                Bitmap output;
                Rect srcRect;
                if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
                    output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    srcRect = new Rect((bitmap.getWidth()-bitmap.getHeight())/2, 0, bitmap.getWidth()+(bitmap.getWidth()-bitmap.getHeight())/2, bitmap.getHeight());
                } else {
                    output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    srcRect = new Rect(0, (bitmap.getHeight()-bitmap.getWidth())/2, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()+(bitmap.getHeight()-bitmap.getWidth())/2);
                }

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
                final int color = 0xff424242;
                final Paint paint = new Paint();
                final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

                float r;

                if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
                    r = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
                } else {
                    r = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
                }

                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
                paint.setColor(color);
                canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, rect, paint);
                return output;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                FirebaseCrash.report(e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setContentText(notificationBody)
                        .setTicker(from + " has responded!")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationBody))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_tabs_notification_2)
                        .setLargeIcon(result);
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, CommentsActivity.class);
                setupPostDetails(notificationBuilder, resultIntent, postId, userId, name, context);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

build.gradle configurations:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.schan.tabs'
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 16
    versionName "1.16"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.Tabs
}
```

If anyone has any idea why this is happening, some insight would be much appreciated. I have a Samsung SM-G900V (Samsung S5) and my friend has a One plus One phone if that helps.

Comment: https://medium.com/exploring-android/android-n-introducing-upgraded-notifications-d4dd98a7ca92#.3xrmucoq2

Answer (score 2):

I think you need provide the new notification icon with the transparent background for Android 6 & upper, so when you set the icon on notification like this:

```
.setSmallIcon(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? R.drawable.ic_notif_with_transparent_bg : R.drawable.ic_notif_current)
```

If you want show the photo, maybe you can try to use the `RemoteViews`

Comment: Hi, yes I totally understand I need a transparent background, but I don't see how that is possible with the photo I want to render. I don't have the image that I want to show stored as a drawable. Can you elaborate on `RemoteViews`?

Comment: maybe you can follow this link for example of RemoteViews https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-loading-images-into-notifications-and-appwidgets. the RemoteViews you need create custom layout for your notifications

Answer (score 0):

Hope It Will help you:

```
int icon = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? R.drawable.your_logo_for_Kitkat :   R.mipmap.your_logo_for_Lolipop_and_uper_version;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(icon)
        .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
        .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("shortDescription"))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setColor(Color.RED)
        .setStyle(notiStyle)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

For Url Load:

```
private class sendNotification extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        Context ctx;
        String message;

    public sendNotification(Context context) {
        super();
        this.ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream in;
        message = params[0] + params[1];
        try {

 URL url = new URL(params[2]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        in = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        return myBitmap;




        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, NotificationsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("isFromBadge", false);


            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
                    .setContentTitle(
                            ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(result).build();

            // hide the notification after its selected
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```